# Overloaded methods receiving higher order functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to have overloaded methods, each accepting a function and nothing else, eg

```
fun foo(a: () -> A) { }
fun foo(b: () -> B) { }
```

In Scala this is not possible, because the functions desugar to instances of `Function0`, and due to erasure these methods cannot be disambiguated. Is this the same case in Kotlin, and if so is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around signature clashes in Kotlin using the `[platformName]` annotation:

```
import kotlin.platform.*

class A
class B

[platformName("foo1")]
fun foo(a: () -> A) { }
fun foo(b: () -> B) { }
```

See the docs [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-platformname)

Comment: Andrey, but Kotlin still cannot select proper overload based on return value only. At least not without specifying types explicitly in function literal. Or can it?

Comment: @ilya-ryzhenkov, no it can't if you use lambdas,  but if you pass already typed values, it can

Comment: `platformName` was renamed to `JvmName`in later Kotlin